# having multiple condition in the config file

Tags: nginx

I would like to have `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` to be executed only for a few cases. I know nginx doesn't support && or || in the conditions and this is a problem for me.

I host a rails application and the easiest way to add SSL support and force my users to always use https was by  changing my config to

```
server {
    listen <my ip>:80;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
...
upstream my_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:9005;
}

server {
    listen <my ip>:443;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    ssl on;
    ....
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }

}
```

This works fine but one of our big customers use Lotus Notes and when they read our newsletters that reference ressources like `<img src="https://mydomain.tld/some-image.png" />`, then they cannot see anything because IE renders in the background, their old IE Version doesn't have SNI support, IE refuses to render the image, everything looks like a mess.

So I decided not to use in our newsletters references to `https` but to `http` instead. So I came up with this configuration:

```
server {
    listen <my ip>:80;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }   


    set $redir_to_ssl ''; 

    if ( $request_uri !~ ^/typo3/ ) { 
        set $redir_to_ssl "${redir_to_ssl}1";
    }   

    if ( $request_uri !~ ^/mailimage/ ) { 
        set $redir_to_ssl "${redir_to_ssl}1";
    }   

    if ( $request_uri !~ ^/ical$ ) { 
        set $redir_to_ssl "${redir_to_ssl}1";
    }   


    if ( $redir_to_ssl = "111" ){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }   
}
```

I still want nginx to automatically redirect anyone to the `https` site, **unless** the URI starts with /typo3 or with /mailimage or with /ical.

So I needed something like this

```
if ( URI does not start with /typo3 AND URI does not start with /mailimage AND ... )
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

I'm not happy with it, it doesn't look that well managed, so I kept searching for better solutions. I found this one [Nginx multiple conditions in if statement](https://serverfault.com/questions/484108/nginx-multiple-conditions-in-if-statement) very intersting, it somehow looks much more cleaner. Should I use it? And how?

So?

```
server {
....
    location /typo3 { 
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }

    location /mailimage { 
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }

    location /ical { 
        proxy_pass http://my_backend;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Would something like this work? And would it be better than my initial solution?

Comment: In your last config put `return 301...` into `location /` and that should be fine.

Comment: There are strong arguments against `if` in nginx config from it's own author Igor Sysoev, so almost anything that works without `if` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a config like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    root /path/to/webroot;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ /(?:typo3|mailimage|ical)/ {
    }
}
```

The second location expression matches either of those locations with the regular expression format, and avoids redirection which is applied to all other locations.

Comment: I'm used using regular expressions (have worked a lot with sed/awk, django, rails, etc) but I'm having trouble understanding `/(?:...)/`. In this case, what does ? match with? And does the `location` order matter? Shouldn't be the `location /` the last one?

Comment: The `?:` means that the contents of the regex won't be captured to any variable. Otherwise the parentheses would make the regex engine capture the expression to a variable `$1` in this case. `location` order doesn't matter in this case, for details, look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html .